# Modelisation of a blockchain

Tags: uml, blockchain, modeling, class-diagram, class-design

I would like to model a blockchain in UML.  Here are the requirements that I came up with:

- User can transfer money
- Money can be transferred from a bank account to a digital wallet
- Money can be transferred from a digital wallet to a bank account
- Money can be transferred to a user (from the contact list)
- User can consult the balance of his portfolio

Here my UML class diagram:

[image]

Since I am new to the blockchain technology, I would like to know: is this diagram correct?  Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not readable.

Comment: Hi Serge and welcome.  Your question is interesting and we would like to help.  Unfortunately, the diagram is not fully readable: I could read Owner, Context, User, Money, Wallet, but not the las class, nor the association labels, nor the cardinality. Could you please take a more precise photo, make a bigger schema, or better model using some digital tool (if needed online, such as for example http://www.umlet.com/umletino/umletino.html )

Comment: sorry I am not in a position to make the diagram on a software, therefore I redid a screenshot. Thanks for your help. click on the next http link
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/prTdi.jpg